# Container/GKE cluster: Force enable Web UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

For a project, I have to create a container/GKE cluster that has the Web UI enabled. The goal is to get the alert related (`WEB_UI_ENABLED`), in order to check how SCC works (it is just for a test environment).

I did some research and discovered that I will have to force the cluster to have a version lower than 1.15, but I can't do that via gcloud (it says the version is unsupported). I have tried to read the documentation or find some tutorial, but I still can't understand how to downgrade or manually edit the `kubernetesDashboard` field of the `addonsConfig` property for the key-value pair `"disabled": false`, since I believe this is also deprecated.

EDIT: I tried the Kubernetes Dashboard open source, but I do not/can not have permissions to use their commands.

Can someone help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to downgrade the cluster version, you can try using the open-source Kubernetes Dashboard. This can be done by deploying the Kubernetes Dashboard as a standalone pod in your cluster.

Here's an example:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

This will create a pod for the Kubernetes Dashboard, as well as a service and a secret for accessing the dashboard. You can then use kubectl to port-forward to the service, in order to access the dashboard.

```
kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard service/kubernetes-dashboard 8443:443
```

Once you access the Kubernetes Dashboard, you can check the service account user and rolebinding.

You would also want to make sure to properly secure access to the dashboard in a production environment. This can be done by configuring authentication and authorization.

I suggest you check the official documentation of the Kubernetes Dashboard installation and its security configuration in detail.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I did not mention, my bad, but I am working for a bigger project, so I do not have permissions to use those commands, nor can they give them to me. This is why I mentioned the downgrade option, although your answer will most likely work, just not for my case...